# Bootstrap Popover from a directive angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I referred the example in the [plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/attribute-directives/ts/plnkr.html) to create a directive and change the background color. I need to do popover a custom html instead of changing background color. How can I acheive it?